# Expectation and variance on joint distribution problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, variance

Two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ have joint distribution $p(x,y)$. How do I show that

1. $E[X] = E_Y[E_X[X|Y]]$
2. $var[X] = E_Y[var_X[X|Y]] + var_Y[E_X[X|Y]]$

I'm not sure how to set up the integrals here and what properties to use.

Comment: These formulas have some amazing geometric consideration via vector projections. I recommend to read it...

Comment: A first step would be to get rid of these horrible $E_Y$ and $E_X$, replacing each of them by $E$. A second step would be to consult a definition of $E(X\mid Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

For (1), we have that by definition of conditional expectations, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_B E_X(X \mid Y) dP = \int_B X dP
\end{align*}
for any $X \in \sigma(Y)$. Letting $B = \Omega$, we recover the tower property
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} E_X(X \mid Y) dP &= \int_{\Omega} X dP  \\
\Rightarrow E_Y(E_X(X \mid Y)) &= E(X).
\end{align*}
I will edit this post to comment on Axolotl's comment about showing (2) using vector projections when I have more time.